# How to make stacked bar chart using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts

So I am having trouble making a stacked bar chart showing proportion of cases vs deaths.
This is the data:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(19108, 19108, 19108, 19108, 
19108, 19108, 19108, 19108, 19108, 19108), class = "Date"), Country = c("US", 
"India", "Brazil", "France", "Germany", "United Kingdom", "Russia", 
"Korea, South", "Italy", "Turkey"), Confirmed = c(81100599L, 
43065496L, 30378061L, 28605614L, 24337394L, 22168390L, 17887152L, 
17086626L, 16191323L, 15023662L), Recovered = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Deaths = c(991940L, 523654L, 663108L, 
146464L, 134489L, 174778L, 367692L, 22466L, 162927L, 98720L), 
    Active = c(80108659L, 42541842L, 29714953L, 28459150L, 24202905L, 
    21993612L, 17519460L, 17064160L, 16028396L, 14924942L)), row.names = c(163539L, 
163431L, 163375L, 163414L, 163418L, 163537L, 163496L, 163444L, 
163437L, 163533L), class = "data.frame")
```

and I want to generate something that looks like this except with proportions of deaths vs cases.

[image]

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: I had updated the post, I was not really sure how to upload data on here until now..

Answer (score 1):

This is a modification of @Allan Cameron's answer with adding the percent label and some other different approaches:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

df %>%
  rename_with(., ~str_replace_all(., 'top10.', '')) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = -Country,
    names_to = "Status",
    values_to = "value", 
    values_transform = list(value = as.integer)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(Status = fct_rev(fct_infreq(Status))) %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>%
  mutate(pct= prop.table(value) * 100) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= Country, y = pct, fill=Status)) +
  geom_col(position = position_fill())+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#ff34b3", "#4976ff")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
  ylab("Percentage") +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", pct),"%")),
            position=position_fill(vjust = 0.1)) +
  ggtitle("Your Title")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to use OCR to convert the image of your data into actual data I could use. It's far better to include your data as text for this reason.

The plot is not particularly informative because the percentages are low, and difficult to read, but in any case, you can do it like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

p <- df %>%
  mutate(top10.Confirmed = top10.Confirmed - top10.Deaths,
         top10.Country = factor(top10.Country, top10.Country)) %>%
  rename(Country = top10.Country, 
         Survived = top10.Confirmed,
         Died = top10.Deaths) %>%
  pivot_longer(-Country, names_to = "Outcome", values_to = "Count") %>%
  mutate(Outcome = factor(Outcome, c("Survived", "Died"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Country, Count, fill = Outcome)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#4976ff", "#ff34b3")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(title = "Covid outcomes by country", y = "Percent")

p
```

[image]

To make it easier to read, you could zoom into the bottom:

```r
p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.05))
```

[image]

---

**Data in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(top10.Country = c("US", "India", "Brazil", "France", 
"Germany", "United Kingdom", "Russia", "Korea, South", "Italy", 
"Turkey"), top10.Confirmed = c(81100599L, 43065496L, 30378061L, 
28605614L, 24337394L, 22168390L, 17887152L, 17086626L, 16191323L, 
15023662L), top10.Deaths = c(991940L, 523654L, 663108L, 146464L, 
134489L, 174778L, 367692L, 22466L, 162927L, 98720L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))

df
#>     top10.Country top10.Confirmed top10.Deaths
#> 1              US        81100599       991940
#> 2           India        43065496       523654
#> 3          Brazil        30378061       663108
#> 4          France        28605614       146464
#> 5         Germany        24337394       134489
#> 6  United Kingdom        22168390       174778
#> 7          Russia        17887152       367692
#> 8    Korea, South        17086626        22466
#> 9           Italy        16191323       162927
#> 10         Turkey        15023662        98720
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks again Allan, you are a lifesaver! I appreciate the work that you do. Next time I shall improve the template for the questions.

Comment: @Allan Cameron I find the approach with `p + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 0.05))` very informative!. I tried in my answer to flip the factors and plot the deaths on top? What do you think?